# Google Earth Engine: Extract band values from pixel in each image of a collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine

sorry for the basic question, I'm a GEE beginner.

Essentially, what I want to do it extract the value of a certain band in a pixel from each image in a collection, and put it into an array.

I understand how to do this if the output is to a chart, e.g.:

```
print(ui.Chart.image.series(with_ndvi.select("nd"),area));
```

Where with_ndvi is my image collection, "nd" is the band I'm interested in, and area is a point feature.

However, I need to get these values into an array, because I need to perform a calculation on each value.

Is there an easy funciton to map over a collection to extract the values as numbers to work with?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, in order to get particular values out of an image, you use `reduceRegion`. Since you have a single point, there isn't exactly any reduction, but the same operation can be used to get the mean, median, maximum, etc. from an area and you need to choose a reducer to perform the operation. (`ui.Chart.image.series` defaults to the `mean` reducer if you don't specify otherwise).

I constructed this example from the images used in the Normalized Difference example script:

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD09GA')
    .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31');

var ndviCollection = imageCollection.map(function (img) {
  var ndImage = img.normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b02', 'sur_refl_b01']);
  return ee.Feature(area, ndImage.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), area));
});

print(ndviCollection);
```

[Runnable example link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0da8d8f04de9c6c44a233d4e6a32d903)

Here, `ndviCollection` is a `FeatureCollection` where each feature has the original point as geometry (useful if you have multiple points of interest, but otherwise you could make it be `null` instead) and the NDVI at that point as a property named `nd`.

If you absolutely need a list of numbers rather than a feature collection, you can obtain that:

```
print(ndviCollection
    .toList(100)  // set this number to the maximum number of elements you expect
    .map(function (feature) { 
      return ee.Feature(feature).get('nd');
    }));
```

but you should not do this if you can avoid it as lists are always kept in memory as a whole rather than processed in a streaming fashion. Instead, perform your computations on the feature collection using `map` and/or `reduceColumns`.